# NoSuchElementException when using do while loop

Tags: java, algorithm, exception

I'm working on my College project and I keep getting this exception when I try to make all my code loop. When not in a loop it works perfectly fine, it includes creating text files and appending text files (if thats any help). My assumption is that my scanner is causing these problems, but I don't know what the problem is or how to fix it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:855)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2108)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2067)
at PDispenser_V1.main(PDispenser_V1.java:51)
```

I can't post my code because plagiarism software checks stackoverflow and my full project will be plagiarised if I do. I know that's a huge downfall but if you could tell me what to look for in general and how to fix it (provided I gave you enough to go on) that would be great! Also the only line number the complier gave me that exists is 51 and it has this code on it.

```
selection = input.nextInt();
```

This line is followed by a switch statement with a bunch of methods in each case. If theres anything I can answer without showing any code please ask. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I should also say, it complies fine but when I go to select one of the options again thats when it throws the exception.

EDIT2: I should also mention that the selection is taking a line from the user not a file.

Comment: Check the input file to see whether it conforms to the format.

Comment: `input` might be closed or no more data to read from it.

Comment: Also please provide a little more code (especially the loop part).

Comment: @nhahtdh selection is just taking the next int from the user to see what case in the switch statement they would like to go too. But yes it does conform to the format, what I'm entering is an int.

Comment: @Nebelmann like I said the switch statement is right after that line and it has a bunch of methods in each case. Its basically all my code. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using nextInt without checking if there is one available to read on the stream, as the [javadoc for nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) says:

> Throws:
>
> NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted

Try using [hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) to check if there is an int before attempting to read one from the stream.

Comment: I'm confused, the selection part is taking the int from the user not a file. (Sorry, I wasn't too clear about that)

Comment: No I'm not, but within the methods that are also in the loop. I do create other scanners instead of passing it into the methods. They aren't closed either

Comment: Are you using Java 7 try-with syntax? That would also close the scanner and its underlying readable. Basically if the input is coming from System.in then it's very likely you have somehow accidentally closed that stream.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is throwing because, there is no next `token` for the `input` to return.

To avoid such `exceptions` it is always best practice to first check the existence of next `token` using `input.hasNextInt()` . If it returns true then extract the next token using `input.nextInt()`. Example.

```
if (input.hasNextInt())
{
   int i = input.nextInt();
}
```

**EDIT**

This Error can be produced in following way:

```
public class Scanned
{
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        Scanner input = null;
        try
        {
            InputStream in = System.in;
            input = new Scanner (in);
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println(input.nextInt());
                in.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that the InputStream is not closed within the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up a little when explaining. Selection = input.nextInt is actually taken from the user not a file.